# How to check if a DateTime occurs today?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Is there a better .net way to check if a DateTime has occured 'today' then the code below?

```
if ( newsStory.WhenAdded.Day == DateTime.Now.Day &&
     newsStory.WhenAdded.Month == DateTime.Now.Month &&
     newsStory.WhenAdded.Year == DateTime.Now.Year )
{ 
    // Story happened today
}
else
{ 
    // Story didn't happen today
}
```

Comment: You may compare newStory.Date == DateTime.Now.Date

Answer (score 258, accepted):

```
if (newsStory.WhenAdded.Date == DateTime.Today)
{

}
else
{

}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: ...if newsStory.Date is actually only the date portion, without time. ;)

Comment: ...which it is, if newsStory is a DateTime

Comment: Well, from what I can see it may just also be some custom class which happens to expose a `Day`, `Month` and `Year` property, no?

Comment: well, DateTime is a part of the .NET Framework Class Library, so while it's *possible* that the OP created his own class that happens to share the same name, you'd have to wonder why he would ask StackOverflow how to use a custom class he created and expect us to magically know how it worked. ;)

Comment: @Dave I really didn't see newsStory as DateTime when I answered the question - maybe due to its naming I thought of it as being a custom class.

Comment: @Lucero that's possible however the question title reads 'two DateTimes'. ;) I guess that's where we got that missing type from.

Comment: Just a sidenote, I tried this but added .AddHours(1) after DateTime.Today (becauset hat DateTime was on a server where the timezone was different from the date I was comparing with), and that resulted in false every time, even though the actual dates were the exact same.

Comment: @HansPetterNaumann that's logical :) DateTime.AddHours() returns a new DateTime object, thus effectively cancelling your .Today operation which indeed didn't have a time component.

Comment: Just FYI: If you are using LINQ to Entities, beware that EF gives an error says that Date is not supported.

Comment: This answer completely ignores the timezone which defines "today". In different time zones today may be a different date.

Comment: @michaelp fair point, however this question is not about timezone compatibility. He presented code which he wanted to simplify; this answer does that. He did not pose a problem with timezones giving different values to today and messing up his evaluation. So while you are correct, the timezone distinction is not needed here. And frankly, it's an odd reason to give negative points on an answer for (I am sure you did that).

Comment: That reply was meant for @MichaelP , apparently tagging does not work on mobile.

Adding to the above; an answer including time zone handling would really increase complexity of the answer. And where would we get the timezone information from? Which dates are Utc and which are not? What's the server timezone? All that relevant information regarding proper handling of timezones is not in the question. So why go there in an answer, when OP is clearly not asking that?

Comment: I admit that using DateTime.Today is enough for local desktop applications, but things are usually more complicated. The right question would always inlcude the meaning of today in certain timezone. Knowing how world timezones work asking just for "today" is not enough.

Comment: @pyrocumulus after years of coding I can tell that .NET does not cover well time domain. Normally we have two types of time - continuous which passes tick by tick, and periodical which may pass in different pace (depending usually on a timezone). Users asking this kind of a question may not be aware, that .NET classes do not distinguish these two time types well (they actually depend on the Kind property which is not very clear). Usually it is safer using continuous time types, but when converting it to date & time, one must answer not only when, but also where.

Comment: I agree that DateTime handling is one of the bigger concerns of larger applications. And also that .NET does not really provide enough tools in that domain. That's where libraries like NodaTime come in; to help solve those deficiencies. But I wouldn't want to go there in a question/answer situation like this. It would probably be considered the smart-ass answer and be ignored in light of more to-the-point answers like I have now. Even though it would technically be more correct :)

Answer (score 31):

```
if( newsStory.Date == DateTime.Today )
{
    // happened today
}
```

Comment: I would like to add, it is a very common (and hard to spot bug) - just comparing the DateTime to a DateTime.Today.

Answer (score 19):

Try

```
if (newsStory.Date == DateTime.Now.Date) 
{ /* Story happened today */ }
else
{ /* Story didn't happen today */ }
```

Answer (score 14):

My solution:

```
private bool IsTheSameDay(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    return (date1.Year == date2.Year && date1.DayOfYear == date2.DayOfYear);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If NewsStory was using a DateTime also, just compare the Date property, and you're done.

However, this depends what "today" actually means. If something is posted shortly before midnight, it will be "old" after a short time. So maybe it would be best to keep the exact story date (including time, preferably UTC) and check if less than 24 hours (or whatever) have passed, which is simple (dates can be subtracted, which gives you a TimeSpan with a TotalHours or TotalDays property).

Answer (score 8):

You can implement a DateTime extension method.

Create new class for your extension methods:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static bool IsSameDay( this DateTime datetime1, DateTime datetime2 )
        {
            return datetime1.Year == datetime2.Year 
                && datetime1.Month == datetime2.Month 
                && datetime1.Day == datetime2.Day;
        }
    }
}
```

And now, everywhere on your code, where do you want to perform this test, you should include the using:

```
using ExtensionMethods;
```

And then, use the extension method:

```
newsStory.WhenAdded.IsSameDay(DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: why not just return datetime1.Date == datetime2.Date ?

Comment: @SergiuMindras is right, it's enough comparing both `Date`'s since it's `TimeSpan` will always be 00:00:00.

Answer (score 7):

As [Guillame](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143503/guillaume) suggested [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601609/how-to-check-if-two-datetimes-occur-on-the-same-day/1601643#comment1466735_1601609), compare values of `Date` properties:

```
newStory.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
```

Answer (score 7):

FYI,

`newsStory.Date == DateTime.Today`

will return the same compare result as coding

`newsStory == DateTime.Today`

where `newsStory` is a `DateTime` object

.NET is smart enough to determine you want to compare based on Date only and uses that for the internal Compare. Not sure why, and actually having trouble finding documentation for this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
newsStory.Date == DateTime.Today
```

Answer (score 1):

well, DateTime has a "Date" property and you could just compare based on that. But looking at the docs it seems that getting that property actually instantiates a new datetime with the time component set to midnight, so it may very well be slower than accessing each individual component, although much cleaner and more readable.

Comment: I think a slowdown(if if exists) will be so small it doesn't matter in almost all cases. Certainly a case of premature optimization.

Comment: Agreed - these days I find it's increasingly difficult to shake out premature optimization as the modern coding world is more about readability and maintainability. Old habits die hard!

Answer (score -2):

How about

```
if (newsStory.DayOfYear == DateTime.Now.DayOfYear)
{ // Story happened today
}
```

But this will also return true for 1st January 2008 and 1st January 2009, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score -6):

you could use `DateTime.Now.DayOfYear`

```
 if (newsStory.DayOfYear == DateTime.Now.DayOfYear)
 { // story happened today

 }
 else
 { // story didn't happen today

 }
```

Comment: I don't think this will work.  If today is 10/21/2009, and newsStory is 10/21/2008 - it will return true (I didn't take leap years into account here).

Comment: This won't discriminate between years

new DateTime(2009, 10, 01).DayOfYear == new DateTime(1900, 10, 01).DayOfYear;