# Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DateTime' and 'string'

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

I have a C# Console Application that gets the Wednesday of the third Tuesday of the month, which works perfectly.

**The issue?**

I want to convert DateTime only to check the date rather than the date with the time.

So, if dd-MM-yyyy is equal to **day** variable (check current code below), do something rather than if dd-MM-yyyy 12:00:00 AM is equaled to **day**

**Current Working Code**

```
DateTime day = new(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
            

            switch (day.DayOfWeek)
            {
                case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                    day.AddDays(17);
                    break;

                case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                    day.AddDays(16);
                    break;

                case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                    day.AddDays(15);
                    break;

                case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                    day.AddDays(21);
                    break;

                case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                    day.AddDays(20);
                    break;

                case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                    day.AddDays(19);
                    break;

                case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                    day.AddDays(18);
                    break;
            }


            if (DateTime.Now != day)
            {
                //Do something here
            }
            else
            {
                //Do something here
            }
```

**What I tried doing and received an error - *Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DateTime' and 'string'***

```
if (DateTime.Now != day.ToString("dd-MM-YYYY"))
            {
                //Do something here
            }
            else
            {
                //Do Something here
            }
```

Overall, I want the program to detect the **Date** portion of the **DateTime** class and do something if that date matches. How would I go about doing this?

Also, I do not want to print out the Date in the output if my words get misinterpreted.

Comment: Its like someone holding up a cat and a picture of a cat, and asking if they are the same. Sure in your head you can reason it, but in actuality a picture isnt a cat. Short story you will need to compare the same type, and that should likely be the `DateTime` Type, or `DateOnly` in .net 6+

Comment: I've removed your `[visual-studio]` tag because this isn't a question about using the Visual Studio application. Please ensure you read tag descriptions before applying them to your question, so as not to misuse them in future.

Comment: Note that .NET 6 introduces the `DateOnly` class, making this easier https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a DateTime occurs today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601609/how-to-check-if-a-datetime-occurs-today)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes no sense to convert a `DateTime` to a string in order to compare it to a `DateTime`.

Use this instead:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Date != day.Date)
```

And you can simplify it to:

```
if (DateTime.Today != day.Date)
```

`.Date` will give you the value of the `DateTime` but with the time component zeroed out (i.e. midnight). `DateTime.Today` is equivalent to `DateTime.Now.Date`.

Comment: The above still reads out 12:00:00 AM with the date when I tried testing it in the console output

Comment: @Broski What's your point? You're making a comparison, not printing a value. If you're printing a value, you'll want to convert it to a _string_ format.

Comment: Perhaps unsurprisingly, this question has been asked and answered before...

Comment: So, I want the program to read the date only so if the date matches, it will do some action. If I include the time, it will only trigger that conditional statement at 12:00:00 as well which I don't want.

Comment: A `DateTime` always has a time component. If you compare two `DateTime` values whose times are both 12:00:00 AM, clearly the time won't factor into the comparison, right?

Comment: Oh right, I thought the time played a factor in this, I guess it doesn't matter. Rookie lesson learnt.