# How to implement Rate limit in Asp.net Framework API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to limit the rate of api calls to avoid DDos attack. What i am trying to achieve is to limit how many calls can be made in one mins to 60 only, or 1 call per second.

I have found the implementation for .net core api, but for .net framwork api, I cannot find anything. Please help.

with ASP.net core api, it looks like this(as gotten from an elmah [blog](https://blog.elmah.io/rate-limiting-api-requests-with-asp-net-core-and-aspnetcoreratelimit/#:%7E:text=We%20use%20AspNetCoreRateLimit%20to%20make%20sure%20that%20users,requests%20per%20minute%20and%203%2C600%20requests%20per%20hour.)).

in the program.cs or startup.cs

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
services.AddSingleton<IClientPolicyStore, MemoryCacheClientPolicyStore>();
services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitCounterStore, MemoryCacheRateLimitCounterStore>();
```

and then add

```
services.Configure<ClientRateLimitOptions>(options =>
{
 options.GeneralRules = new List<RateLimitRule>
 {
    new RateLimitRule
    {
        Endpoint = "*",
        Period = "1m",
        Limit = 500,
    },
    new RateLimitRule
    {
        Endpoint = "*",
        Period = "1h",
        Limit = 3600,
    }
  };
});
```

How to do one for ASP.net framework API?

Comment: Hello. Author here. I have come across WebApiThrottle and do not understand what happened there.

Comment: It is probably useless right now, but if your app is planned to be released in December or later, you might want to check out this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMTvNnKt3AA It explains a new rate limiting functionality in .NET 7 which is exactly what you are looking for. However .NET 7 is not released yet, and is planned to release this november.

Comment: If only. This project is a bit troublesome. I am updating an old project. and it uses old dependency. I am not allowed to upgrade the project. Thanks @Joost00719

Answer (score 0):

As of the time i am writing this code, I have not seen solution i could use, so I created mine.

I created a task/Service  that is called in the controller. this task is as thus:

```
 public bool IsWithinRangeLimit()
    {
        var dbEntities = new DbEntities();
        var isWithinRangeLimit = true;
        int rangeLimitNumber = int.Parse( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RateLimitNumber"].ToString() );
        int timeSpanInMins = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RateLimitTimeInMins"].ToString() );



        try
        {

            var requestList = dbEntities.RequestTrackers.ToList();
            Random rd = new Random();
            int rand_num = rd.Next(100000, 30000000);
            var newTracker = new RequestTracker()
            {
                id = rand_num,
                requestDate = DateTime.Now
            };


          
            if (!requestList.Any())
            {
                dbEntities.RequestTrackers.Add(newTracker);
                dbEntities.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                var reqListOrganised = requestList.OrderByDescending(m => m.requestDate).Take(rangeLimitNumber);
                var endTime = DateTime.Now;
                var starttime = endTime.AddMinutes(-timeSpanInMins);
                var tenthDate = reqListOrganised.LastOrDefault().requestDate;


                if (starttime <= tenthDate && tenthDate <= endTime)
                {
                    isWithinRangeLimit = false;


                    
                }
                else
                {
                    dbEntities.RequestTrackers.Add(newTracker);
                    dbEntities.SaveChanges();
                }

                
            }
            
            
        }
        catch
        {
        }


        foreach (var item in dbEntities.RequestTrackers)
        {
            var isSAmeDay = this.IsSameDay(DateTime.Now, item.requestDate);
            if (!isSAmeDay)
            {
                dbEntities.RequestTrackers.Remove(item);

            }
            
        }
        dbEntities.SaveChanges();
        return isWithinRangeLimit;
        


    }
```

The isSameDay class i added can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601609/how-to-check-if-a-datetime-occurs-today.).

the data comes in from web.config. It looks as thus:

```
  <add key="RateLimitTimeInMins" value="1" />
  <add key="RateLimitNumber" value="2" />
```

'Idealy' you will want to create an autoincrement able Primary Key, and want to dispose not needed date from the database using time dependent services.

**Please add answer if you have a better solution**